# MongoDB .NET: one-to-many? many-to-many?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am currently enjoying writing an API using MongoDB with the .NET drivers for C#. I am finding it very easy to use, but I am wondering how I go about specifying one-to-many relationships, without using embedded documents. Also, many-to-many will soon become an issue.

Unfortunately, the Microsoft documentation is extremely dry and it's difficult to discern how to go about creating relationships between objects in the database, without embedding them in the same document.

I have a POCO like this:

```
public class UserModel : DocumentModel
{
  public ProfileModel Profille { get; set; }
  public string DefaultReadLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like the `Profile` to be in its own document, not embedded in the `UserModel`. Is this possible? Or is it just a case of storing the ID of the profile in the user document? That would be a shame. :(

Answer (score 1):

Document databases like MongoDB are not built for relational data modeling, so if you want to build a data model that relies on relationships, maybe it isn't a good fit for the problem.

If you want to store references to documents that you don't want to embed, store the Id and manually retrieve the linked document. But do note that you need to handle any referential integrity yourself and deal with possibly missing data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't believe it to be entirely correct. The MongoDB documentation itself talks about one-to-many relationships with document references, and then there is the $lookup aggregation operator. My question is has this functionality made its way into the C# MongoDB library? Are there any attributes or decorators you can apply to POCO members to indicate a document reference or is it - as you say - a matter of storing the IDs and doing the joins manually?